# How to discover devices connected to my router using Java Android API

Tags: java, android, networking, router

Please I would to build an android app that can discover all devices connected to my network, their SSID and IP address, here is a simple try but it doesn't convey me,

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet){
   int timeout=1000;
   for (int i=1;i<255;i++){
       String host=subnet + "." + i;
       if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
           System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
       }
   }
}
```

is there any idea to do this task, I am blocked in 2 months ago?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of devices connected to a wi-fi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212484/list-of-devices-connected-to-a-wi-fi-network)

Comment: This method use services, I would to do general discovering to get the devices connected to my router

Comment: Any Ida please?